# Running Jetty webserver

Tags: web-server

I just installed Jetty 6.1.18 on my raspberry pi via apt-get but I have trouble running it.

It works fine when using the start.jar directly (in /usr/share/jetty) with `sudo java -jar start.jar`, so I can see the "welcome to Jetty" html page when pointing a browser to my pi's IP address

But if it doesn't work if I start it using `sudo /etc/init.d/jetty start` although the output is:

```
[....] Starting Jetty servlet engine.: jetty Rotate logs[....] Jetty servlet engine started, reachable on http://raspberrypi:8080/.: jetty.
```

so no apparent warnings or problems...

Using OpenJDK as JVM, output of `echo $JAVA_HOME` is `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-armhf`

and I edited `/etc/default/jetty` to reflect `$JAVA_HOME` there

Has anybody seen a similar issue with jetty or other webservers? Obviously, I'd like the init.d script to work, so that the webserver is up and running at startup automatically...

For info, here is the actual /etc/init.d/jetty script:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# /etc/init.d/jetty -- startup script for jetty 6.1.18
#
# Written by Philipp Meier <meier@meisterbohne.de>
# Modified for Jetty 6 by Ludovic Claude <ludovic.claude@laposte.net>
#
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          jetty
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs $network
# Should-Start:      $named
# Should-Stop:       $named
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start Jetty
# Description:       Start Jetty HTTP server and servlet container.
### END INIT INFO

# Configuration files
#
# /etc/default/jetty
#   If it exists, this is read at the start of script. It may perform any 
#   sequence of shell commands, like setting relevant environment variables.
#
# /etc/jetty/jetty.conf
#   If found, the file will be used as this script's configuration. 
#   Each line in the file may contain:
#     - A comment denoted by the pound (#) sign as first non-blank character.
#     - The path to a regular file, which will be passed to jetty as a 
#       config.xml file.
#     - The path to a directory. Each *.xml file in the directory will be
#       passed to jetty as a config.xml file.
#
#   The files will be checked for existence before being passed to jetty.
#
# /etc/jetty/jetty.xml
#   If found, used as this script's configuration file, but only if
#   /etc/jetty/jetty.conf was not present. See above.
#   
# Configuration variables (to define in /etc/default/jetty)
#
# JAVA_HOME  
#   Home of Java installation. 
#
# JAVA_OPTIONS
#   Extra options to pass to the JVM
#
# JETTY_PORT
#   Override the default port for Jetty servers. If not set then 8080
#   will be used. The java system property "jetty.port" will be set to 
#   this value for use in configure.xml files. For example, the following 
#   idiom is widely used in the demo config files to respect this property 
#   in Listener configuration elements:
#
#    <Set name="Port"><SystemProperty name="jetty.port" default="8080"/></Set>
#
# JETTY_ARGS
#   The default arguments to pass to jetty.
#
# JETTY_USER
#   if set, then used as a username to run the server as

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
NAME=jetty
DESC="Jetty servlet engine"
JETTY_HOME=/usr/share/$NAME
LOGDIR="/var/log/jetty"
START_JAR="$JETTY_HOME/start.jar"
START_DAEMON_JAR="$JETTY_HOME/start-daemon.jar"
DEFAULT=/etc/default/$NAME
DAEMON=/usr/bin/jsvc
JVM_TMP=/var/cache/jetty/tmp

if [ `id -u` -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "You need root privileges to run this script"
    exit 1
fi

# Make sure jetty is started with system locale
if [ -r /etc/default/locale ]; then
    . /etc/default/locale
    export LANG
fi

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

if [ -r /etc/default/rcS ]; then
    . /etc/default/rcS
fi


# The following variables can be overwritten in /etc/default/jetty

# Whether to start jetty (as a daemon) or not
NO_START=0

# Run Jetty as this user ID (default: jetty)
# Set this to an empty string to prevent Jetty from starting automatically
JETTY_USER=jetty

# Listen to connections from this network host (leave empty to accept all connections)
#JETTY_HOST=$(uname -n)
JETTY_HOST=

# The network port used by Jetty
JETTY_PORT=8080

# Additional arguments to pass to Jetty    
JETTY_ARGS=

# Extra options to pass to the JVM         
# Set java.awt.headless=true if JAVA_OPTIONS is not set so the
# Xalan XSL transformer can work without X11 display on JDK 1.4+
# It also sets the maximum heap size to 256M to deal with most cases.
JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx256m -Djava.awt.headless=true"

# The first existing directory is used for JAVA_HOME (if JAVA_HOME is not
# defined in /etc/default/jetty). Should contain a list of space separated directories.
JDK_DIRS="
      /usr/lib/jvm/default-java \
      /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun \
      /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk \
      /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-sun \
      /usr/lib/jvm/java-gcj \
      /usr/lib/j2sdk1.6-sun \
      /usr/lib/j2sdk1.5-sun \
      /usr/lib/j2sdk1.5-ibm \
      /usr/lib/j2sdk1.4-sun \
      /usr/lib/j2sdk1.4 \
      /usr/lib/j2se/1.4 \
      /usr/lib/kaffe/ \
     "

# Timeout in seconds for the shutdown of all webapps
JETTY_SHUTDOWN=30

# Jetty uses a directory to store temporary files like unpacked webapps
JETTY_TMP=/var/cache/jetty/data

# Jetty uses a config file to setup its boot classpath
JETTY_START_CONFIG=/etc/jetty/start.config

# End of variables that can be overwritten in /etc/default/jetty

# overwrite settings from default file
if [ -f "$DEFAULT" ]; then
    . "$DEFAULT"
fi

# Check whether jetty is still installed (it might not be if this package was
# removed and not purged)
if [ ! -r "$START_JAR" ]; then
    log_failure_msg "$NAME is not installed"
    exit 1
fi

[ -f "$DAEMON" ] || exit 0

# Check whether startup has been disabled
if [ "$NO_START" != "0" -a "$1" != "stop" ]; then 
    [ "$VERBOSE" != "no" ] && log_failure_msg "Not starting jetty - edit /etc/default/jetty and change NO_START to be 0 (or comment it out)."
    exit 0
fi

if [ -z "$JETTY_USER" ]; then
    log_failure_msg "Not starting/stopping $DESC as configured"
    log_failure_msg "(JETTY_USER is empty in /etc/default/jetty)."
    exit 0
fi

# Look for the right JVM to use
for jdir in $JDK_DIRS; do
    if [ -d "$jdir" -a -z "${JAVA_HOME}" ]; then
        JAVA_HOME="$jdir"
    fi
done
export JAVA_HOME

export JAVA="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"

JAVA_OPTIONS="$JAVA_OPTIONS -Djava.io.tmpdir=$JETTY_TMP \
  -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib -DSTART=$JETTY_START_CONFIG \
  -Djetty.home=$JETTY_HOME -Djetty.logs=$LOGDIR \
  -Djetty.host=$JETTY_HOST -Djetty.port=$JETTY_PORT"

# Set the JSP compiler if set in the jetty.default file
if [ -n "$JSP_COMPILER" ]; then
    JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dbuild.compiler=$JSP_COMPILER"
fi

export JAVA_OPTIONS

# Define other required variables
PIDFILE="/var/run/$NAME.pid"
WEBAPPDIR="$JETTY_HOME/webapps"
BOOTSTRAP_CLASS=org.mortbay.jetty.start.daemon.Bootstrap
JSVC_CLASSPATH="/usr/share/java/commons-daemon.jar:$START_JAR:$START_DAEMON_JAR:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar"
ROTATELOGS=/usr/sbin/rotatelogs
HOSTNAME=$(uname -n)

##################################################
# Check for JAVA_HOME
##################################################
if [ -z "$JAVA_HOME" ]; then
    log_failure_msg "Could not start $DESC because no Java Development Kit"
    log_failure_msg "(JDK) was found. Please download and install JDK 1.4 or higher and set"
    log_failure_msg "JAVA_HOME in /etc/default/jetty to the JDK's installation directory."
    exit 0
fi

CONFIG_LINES=$(cat /etc/jetty/jetty.conf | grep -v "^[:space:]*#" | tr "\n" " ")

##################################################
# Get the list of config.xml files from jetty.conf
##################################################
if [ ! -z "${CONFIG_LINES}" ] 
then
  for CONF in ${CONFIG_LINES} 
  do
    if [ ! -r "$CONF" ] 
    then
      log_warning_msg "WARNING: Cannot read '$CONF' specified in '$JETTY_CONF'" 
    elif [ -f "$CONF" ] 
    then
      # assume it's a configure.xml file
      CONFIGS="$CONFIGS $CONF" 
    elif [ -d "$CONF" ] 
    then
      # assume it's a directory with configure.xml files
      # for example: /etc/jetty.d/
      # sort the files before adding them to the list of CONFIGS
      XML_FILES=`ls ${CONF}/*.xml | sort | tr "\n" " "` 
      for FILE in ${XML_FILES} 
      do
         if [ -r "$FILE" ] && [ -f "$FILE" ] 
         then
            CONFIGS="$CONFIGS $FILE" 
         else
           log_warning_msg "WARNING: Cannot read '$FILE' specified in '$JETTY_CONF'" 
         fi
      done
    else
      log_warning_msg "WARNING: Don''t know what to do with '$CONF' specified in '$JETTY_CONF'" 
    fi
  done
fi

#####################################################
# Run the standard server if there's nothing else to run
#####################################################
if [ -z "$CONFIGS" ]
then
    CONFIGS="/etc/jetty/jetty-logging.xml /etc/jetty/jetty.xml"
fi

##################################################
# Do the action
##################################################
case "$1" in
  start)
    log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC." "$NAME"
    if start-stop-daemon --quiet --test --start --pidfile "$PIDFILE" \
                    --user "$JETTY_USER" --startas "$JAVA" > /dev/null; then 

        if [ -f $PIDFILE ] ; then
            log_warning_msg "$PIDFILE exists, but jetty was not running. Ignoring $PIDFILE"
        fi

        if [ -s "$LOGDIR/out.log" ]; then
            log_progress_msg "Rotate logs"
            $ROTATELOGS "$LOGDIR/out.log" 86400 \
                < "$LOGDIR/out.log" || true
        fi
        > "$LOGDIR/out.log"
        chown -R $JETTY_USER:adm "$LOGDIR"

        # Remove / recreate JETTY_TMP directory
        rm -rf "$JETTY_TMP"
        mkdir "$JETTY_TMP" || {
            log_failure_msg "could not create $DESC temporary directory at $JETTY_TMP"
            exit 1
        }
        chown $JETTY_USER "$JETTY_TMP"

        # Remove / recreate JVM_TMP directory
        rm -rf "$JVM_TMP"
        mkdir "$JVM_TMP" || {
            log_failure_msg "could not create JVM temporary directory at $JVM_TMP"
            exit 1
        }
        chown $JETTY_USER "$JVM_TMP"
        cd "$JVM_TMP"

        $DAEMON -user "$JETTY_USER" -cp "$JSVC_CLASSPATH" \
            -outfile $LOGDIR/out.log -errfile $LOGDIR/out.log \
            -pidfile "$PIDFILE" $JAVA_OPTIONS $BOOTSTRAP_CLASS \
            $JETTY_ARGS $CONFIGS

        log_daemon_msg "$DESC started, reachable on http://$HOSTNAME:$JETTY_PORT/." "$NAME"

        sleep 5
        if start-stop-daemon --test --start --pidfile "$PIDFILE" \
            --user $JETTY_USER --startas "$JAVA" >/dev/null; then
            log_end_msg 1
        else
            log_end_msg 0
        fi

    else
        log_warning_msg "(already running)."
        log_end_msg 0
        exit 1
    fi
    ;;

  stop)
    log_daemon_msg "Stopping $DESC (was reachable on http://$HOSTNAME:$JETTY_PORT/)." "$NAME"

    if start-stop-daemon --quiet --test --start --pidfile "$PIDFILE" \
        --user "$JETTY_USER" --startas "$JAVA" > /dev/null; then
        if [ -x "$PIDFILE" ]; then
            log_warning_msg "(not running but $PIDFILE exists)."
        else
            log_warning_msg "(not running)."
        fi
    else
        start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop \
            --pidfile "$PIDFILE" --user "$JETTY_USER" \
            --startas "$JAVA" > /dev/null
        while ! start-stop-daemon --quiet --test --start \
              --pidfile "$PIDFILE" --user "$JETTY_USER" \
              --startas "$JAVA" > /dev/null; do 
            sleep 1
            log_progress_msg "."
            JETTY_SHUTDOWN=`expr $JETTY_SHUTDOWN - 1` || true
            if [ $JETTY_SHUTDOWN -ge 0 ]; then
                start-stop-daemon --oknodo --quiet --stop \
                    --pidfile "$PIDFILE" --user "$JETTY_USER" \
                    --startas "$JAVA"
            else
                log_progress_msg " (killing) "
                start-stop-daemon --stop --signal 9 --oknodo \
                    --quiet --pidfile "$PIDFILE" \
                    --user "$JETTY_USER"
            fi
        done
        rm -f "$PIDFILE"
        rm -rf "$JVM_TMP"
        rm -rf "$JETTY_TMP/*"
        log_daemon_msg "$DESC stopped." "$NAME"
        log_end_msg 0
    fi
    ;;

  status)
    if start-stop-daemon --quiet --test --start --pidfile "$PIDFILE" \
        --user "$JETTY_USER" --startas "$JAVA" > /dev/null; then

        if [ -f "$PIDFILE" ]; then
            log_success_msg "$DESC is not running, but pid file exists."
            exit 1
        else
            log_success_msg "$DESC is not running."
            exit 3
        fi
    else
        log_success_msg "$DESC is running with pid `cat $PIDFILE`, and is reachable on http://$JETTY_HOST:$JETTY_PORT/"
    fi
    ;;

  restart|force-reload)
    if ! start-stop-daemon --quiet --test --start --pidfile "$PIDFILE" \
        --user "$JETTY_USER" --startas "$JAVA" > /dev/null; then
        $0 stop $*
        sleep 1
    fi
    $0 start $*
    ;;

  try-restart)
    if start-stop-daemon --quiet --test --start --pidfile "$PIDFILE" \
        --user "$JETTY_USER" --startas "$JAVA" > /dev/null; then
        $0 start $*
    fi
    ;;

  check)
    log_success_msg "Checking arguments for Jetty: "
    log_success_msg ""
    log_success_msg "PIDFILE        =  $PIDFILE"
    log_success_msg "JAVA_OPTIONS   =  $JAVA_OPTIONS"
    log_success_msg "JAVA           =  $JAVA"
    log_success_msg "JETTY_USER     =  $JETTY_USER"
    log_success_msg "JETTY_HOST     =  $JETTY_HOST"
    log_success_msg "JETTY_PORT     =  $JETTY_PORT"
    log_success_msg "ARGUMENTS      =  $ARGUMENTS"

    if [ -f $PIDFILE ]
    then
        log_success_msg "$DESC is running with pid `cat $PIDFILE`, and is reachable on http://$JETTY_HOST:$JETTY_PORT/"
        exit 0
    fi
    exit 1
    ;;

  *)
    log_success_msg "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|force-reload|try-restart|status|check}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Comment: What Java are you using?  Does `sudo /etc/init.d/jetty start` output anything?  I don't have jetty installed, can you post the contents of `/etc/init.d/jetty`?

Comment: edited my question with more info

Comment: similar question here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296095/starting-jetty-via-launch-script-does-not-work) but no answers

Comment: Define "Doesn't work".

Comment: I tried installing it on my Pi and when it starts it's only listening on `tcp6` ports for some reason.  I changed `JETTY_HOST` to `0.0.0.0`, but again it's only listening on tcp6 port 8080.

Comment: I take my previous comment back. Jetty is working for me.  I was confused over the output of the netstat command which showed `tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN` for Jetty's listen.  I thought that meant IP V6 only, but it obviously doesn't since it is working for me.  I had to edit `/etc/default/jetty` setting `JETTY_HOST` to `0.0.0.0` to allow any host to connect.

Comment: ah! setting `JETTY_HOST` to `0.0.0.0` did the trick for me too. Although it is explicitly stated in `/etc/default/jetty`, I didn't quite understand what he meant. Cheers!
@HeatfanJohn, If you put this down as answer, I'll accept it then

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default configuration for Jetty in `/etc/default/jetty` only allows connections from `localhost`, you need to set `JETTY_HOST` to `0.0.0.0` to allow Jetty to accept connections from any host.

Add the following line to `/etc/default/jetty`:

```
JETTY_HOST 0.0.0.0
```